# Unwanted blank pages appear between part and chapter

Tags: titlesec, books, titletoc

I am using `book` class together with `titlesec`, `fancyhdr` and `titletoc` packages. The problem appears when using `\printcontents` to print the partial ToC after the part.

The "some text" appears on the next odd page after the chapter.

```
\part{One}

Some text

\chapter{First}
```

[image]

But I want it to appear right after the partial ToC.

My MWE (I use LuaLaTeX, if it matters)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[newparttoc,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage[%
    hidelinks,%
    final,%
]{hyperref}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont}
{Part~\thepart}
{1cm}
{\Huge\bfseries#1}[{
    \startcontents[parts]
    \normalsize
    \normalfont
    \mdseries
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \printcontents[parts]{p}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
}]

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents



    \part{One}

    Some text

    \chapter{First}


    \section{1}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `book` class, chapters   start a new odd page by default.

Comment: @Bernard yes, but I am talking about the "some text", not the next chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Both `book.cls` and `titlesec.sty` control the blank page coming with the part, please place the below tags after the command `\begin{document}` which solves the issue:

```
\documentclass[openany,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[newparttoc,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage[%
    hidelinks,%
    final,%
]{hyperref}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont}
{Part~\thepart}
{1cm}
{\Huge\bfseries#1}[{
    \startcontents[parts]
    \normalsize
    \normalfont
    \mdseries
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \printcontents[parts]{p}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
}]

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{%\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                %\newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\def\ttl@page@ii#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{ttl@ps@#6}%
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
    {\thispagestyle{\@nameuse{ttl@ps@#6}}}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \vspace*{\@tempskipa}%
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifcase#5 \@afterindentfalse\fi
  \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
  \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}%
  \ttl@finmarks
  \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}%
  \vspace{\@tempskipb}%
%  \newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \@ifundefined{ttl@ps@#6}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}}%
        {\thispagestyle{\@nameuse{ttl@ps@#6}}}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents



    \part{One}

    Some text

    \chapter{First}


    \section{1}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: The text still appears on the next page, not right after the ToC.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please try it ...